# Formik Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup, react-proptypes

I am using Formik to handle forms in a next Js project but I keep getting this weird error:

```
Warning: Invalid field name. Either pass `useField` a string or an object containing a `name` key.
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Nothing I have tried is working. This is not my first time of using Formik which makes this error somewhat weird. I have checked all my formik input components and can't seem to find any issues with my return statements.

Here is my `<InputField />` Component using Formik:

```
import { ErrorMessage, useField } from 'formik';
import { HiExclamationCircle } from 'react-icons/hi';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

InputFieldOverflow.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  variant: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.string,
};

function InputField({
  label,
  name,
  placeholder,
  variant,
  size,
  ...props
}) {
  const [ field, meta ] = useField(props);

  return (
    <>
      {label && (
        <label htmlFor={name} className="block sm:text-sm text-xs font-normal text-theblack mb-[5px]">
          {label}
        </label>
      )}

      <div className="relative">
        <input
          {...field}
          {...props}
          type="text"
          id={name}
          className={classNames(
            "block w-full rounded-lg shadow-xs  sm:text-sm text-xs placeholder-body",
            {
              'focus:ring-error border-error focus:border-error': meta.touched && meta.error,
              'focus:ring-success border-gray-stroke focus:border-success' : !meta.touched && !meta.error,
              'bg-white ': variant === 'primary',
              'bg-input text-body': variant === 'secondary',
              'sm:h-[60px] h-[50px]': size === 'big',
              'sm:h-[50px] h-[50px]': size === 'small',
              'h-[180px]': size === 'textArea',
            }
          )}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          aria-describedby={name}
        />

        {meta.touched && meta.error && (
          <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-3 pointer-events-none">
            <HiExclamationCircle className="text-xl text-error" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <ErrorMessage component="p" name={field.name} className="text-xs text-error mt-[5px]" />
    </>
  );
}

export default InputField;
```

Here is how I use it a page

```
import InputField from '@/components/Fields/InputField';
import Button from '@/components/Button/Button';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

import { withSettingsNavLayout } from '@/layouts/dashboard/settings-nav';


function MyAccount() {

  const formValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    fullName: Yup.string().min(8, "Full name must be at least 8 characters long").max(30, "Full name must not be more than 30 characters long").required("Full name is required"),
    userName: Yup.string().min(5, "Username must be at least 5 characters long").max(15, "Username must not be more than 15 characters long").required("username is required"),
  });

  const formInitialValues = {
    fullName: 'John Doe',
    userName: 'johndoe2022',
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="sm:mt-[34px] mt-[25px] md:ml-[30px] md:mr-[81px] mx-[10px] w-full sm:w-[610px]">
        <Formik
          initialValues={formInitialValues}
          validationSchema={formValidationSchema}
        >
          {() => (
            <Form>
              <InputField
                name="fullName"
                label="Full Name"
                variant="secondary"
                size="small"
              />
              <div className="mt-[30px]">
                <InputField
                  name="userName"
                  label="Username"
                  variant="secondary"
                  size="small"
                />
              </div>
              <Button 
                type="submit"
                variant="secondary"
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default withSettingsNavLayout(MyAccount);
```

What is causing this weird error and how can I fix it.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Console log your entire component and take a close look at its children. Somewhere in there, an object isn't what you think it is. Create a reproducible repository so people can test it locally and help you better. Cheers

Comment: I finally fixed it @PSavva

Comment: Super. I'm glad

Answer (score 0):

I finally got rid of the error. The error occurred because I declared the `name` prop in the component which made it unavailable in `...props` for `useField` to consume. Since `useField(props)` couldn't get the `name` property, it was returning `[Object Object]` hence the error:

```
Warning: Invalid field name. Either pass `useField` a string or an object containing a `name` key.
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

To fix it, I refactored my component by removing `name` declaration from the props. I also changed all instances of `name` to `field.name`.

Below is the working refactored `<InputField />` component:

```
import { ErrorMessage, useField } from 'formik';
import { HiExclamationCircle } from 'react-icons/hi';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

InputFieldOverflow.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  variant: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.string,
};

/* name no longer declared among the props for InputField which makes it available in ...props for useField to consume.*/

function InputField({
  label,
  placeholder,
  variant,
  size,
  ...props
}) {
  const [ field, meta ] = useField(props);

  return (
    <>
      {label && (
        <label htmlFor={field.name} className="block sm:text-sm text-xs font-normal text-theblack mb-[5px]">
          {label}
        </label>
      )}

      <div className="relative">
        <input
          {...field}
          {...props}
          type="text"
          id={field.name}
          className={classNames(
            "block w-full rounded-lg shadow-xs  sm:text-sm text-xs placeholder-body",
            {
              'focus:ring-error border-error focus:border-error': meta.touched && meta.error,
              'focus:ring-success border-gray-stroke focus:border-success' : !meta.touched && !meta.error,
              'bg-white ': variant === 'primary',
              'bg-input text-body': variant === 'secondary',
              'sm:h-[60px] h-[50px]': size === 'big',
              'sm:h-[50px] h-[50px]': size === 'small',
              'h-[180px]': size === 'textArea',
            }
          )}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          aria-describedby={field.name}
        />

        {meta.touched && meta.error && (
          <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-3 pointer-events-none">
            <HiExclamationCircle className="text-xl text-error" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <ErrorMessage component="p" name={field.name} className="text-xs text-error mt-[5px]" />
    </>
  );
}

export default InputField;
```